# Defining TableView onMousePressed actions in FXML

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, fxml

I've got a Java project I'm working on that uses JavaFX to generate a UI. I'm not much of a Java programmer (not much of a programmer in general - I'm a CS student), so it's a bit of a learning experience, but generally I'm answering my own questions as I go. I'm now hitting a sticky spot with a TableView, though, and getting a bit lost - specifically, I can't seem to set any kind of action in response to interacting with the TableView.

The current layout of my project is Main.java, Controller.java and UI.fxml. In Main the pane/scene is loaded from UI.fxml as the program starts. (Technically the project contains several other bits of code, but I'm trying to only post what's relevant.) I have a TableView defined in UI.fxml as so:

```
<TableView fx:id="queueTable">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn text="Title">
             <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="tableTitle"/>
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn text="Artist">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="tableArtist"/>
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn text="Album">
        <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="tableAlbum"/>
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

Similarly I have several buttons defined in UI.fxml with onAction as so:

```
<Button fx:id="buttonQueueAdd" text="Add" onAction="#addMediaToQueue"/>
```

In my previous code I was able to define an event for when an item in the TableView was selected, in the method where my TableView was being generated. Now, however, all the UI creation is done via the FXML file. The FXML file has a controller class it refers to (Controller.java), where all the actions are defined for the various buttons, but I can't seem to get it to accept any attribute like `onAction`, `setOnMousePressed`, etc. in the FXML file for the TableView like it accepts an 'onAction' attribute for the Button.

It seems like I can get a workaround going by defining the action in my Main class (or creating a method in my Controller class that's called in the Main class, when the scene is being created), but that won't work unless I make `queueTable` static in my Controller class... which then breaks all the functions that manipulate items in the TableView - for example, I can no longer add items to the TableView/the UI does not refresh to show items are added.

It seems like the best solution is to not have the TableView created in FXML, to instead have the TableView created and all its onMousePressed events and etc. set up outside of the FXML file and have them added to the scene in my Main class's `start` method. This is how it was done previously, and it worked acceptably then. However, that seems messy, and leads to my UI elements being strewn across multiple classes and/or the FXML file - this is a project I'm working on with several other students, and I'm trying to keep everything as streamlined/organized as possible. Do I have to bite the bullet and do it the "messy" way, or is there a better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still generate the `TableView` using the fxml, but add a `initialize` method to the controller. This method is invoked by the `FXMLLoader` after it's done creating the object stucture and can be used to do modifications to the object structure that you cannot do from fxml:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    queueTable.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        ...
    });
}
```

---

In case you need to add this listener from `Main`, you could add a method to the controller and get the controller from the `FXMLLoader` instance you use to create the fxml.

**Controller**

```
public void addSelectedIndexListener(ChangeListener<? super Number> listener) {
    queueTable.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(listener);
}
```

**Main**

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(fxmlUrl);
myNode = loader.load();
Controller controller = loader.getController();
controller.addSelectedIndexListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    ...
});
```

---

Note that is an property property should depend on a property of the selection model, you may be able to use [expression binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding) to achieve the desired effect.

```xml
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <center>
        <TableView fx:id="table" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn text="value">
                    <cellValueFactory>
                        <PropertyValueFactory property="value"/>
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
            </columns>
            <items>
                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                    <Item value="Hello World"/>
                    <Item value="42"/>
                </FXCollections>
            </items>
        </TableView>
    </center>
    <left>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Remove" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" disable="${table.selectionModel.selectedIndex+0&lt;0}" />
    </left>
</BorderPane>
```

Note that the `table.selectionModel.selectedIndex+0<0` part is a workaround used, since JavaFX currently doesn't use `null`-safe equality checks (`table.selectionModel.selectedItem==null` doesn't work) and cannot get the type of the `0` constant right for comparison (`table.selectionModel.selectedIndex<0`), so this currently doesn't seem like a good option.